# Figure out reason for wakeup

Tags: suspend, synology

So I have this Synology NAS (DS213+) at home, which apparently uses a rather limited custom Linux (2.6.32.12). For quite some time now I noticed it starting up frequently, even though I'm not accessing it from any device within my home network and I cannot think of any reason why this is happening.

Can anybody tell me how I can monitor the reason for the wakeups? I read about using `systemd` of inspecting `/var/log/syslog`, however both are not present on this system.